# Is it possible to create a polygon using lat.lon in Tableau

Tags: polygon, tableau-api

I want to draw a polygon ( or even better to use already defined lat.long) in Tableau map.

is it possible?

Regards

Comment: Tha is exactly how most maps were drawn before Tableau 10.2 introduced reading geospatial files directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, choose the polygon mark type, put latitude and longitude on the row and column shelves and a field on the path shelf to specify point order.

Use other dimensions on additional shelves such as detail or color if you have multiple polygons to display